# Execute python script from within HTML

Tags: python, html

On my raspberry pi i have apache2 running. i have a very basic image displayed when you go to the site. What i want to be able to do is, when the image is clicked i want the following script to run.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('./milight_sources/milight 0 ON', shell=True)
```

Now, i'm pretty sure django isn't the answer and neither is Flask. can you suggest the best way to do this? perhaps i don't even need to use a framework at all?

I'm pulling my hair out over this and am determinted to get it working. any suggestions will be great.

Many thanks!

Comment: A template system like jinja? http://jinja.pocoo.org

Comment: It's pretty easy to do using cgi-bin. Add the python file to your cgi-bin folder, make sure .py files are enabled for cgi scripts, chmod the python file to 755, then add a javascript redirect when someone clicks on the image. You can also add a redirect at the bottom of the python file to return to the webpage you were on.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I am looking for. Something simple and I've just read through how the cgi-bin works and it's exactly what I need. thank you thank you thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a small script that utilizes cgi should do the job

https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html